# Show specific menu only on one page

Tags: meteor

I've navigation menu and I would like to display the helper menu button only when the user is on specific page and be hided on others.

I've tried this way, but that doest worked

```
{{#if Store}}
<a href="#menu-toggle" class="toggle" id="menu-toggle">Filters</a>
{{/if}}
```

Can you please suggest how achieve this function?

Comment: you need to look up what page you are on with the Router you are one, then set a variable you can use in the template. What Router do you use?

Comment: @mre I've picked up iron:router

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your template helper, you can lookup the route name with

`Router.current().route.getName()`

then you can set a helper variable to lookup if you are on this page.

```
Template.mytemplate.helpers({
    'Store': function() {
          return Router.current().route.getName() == 'Store'; //the Route name
    }
});
```

then use the `Store` variable in your template as you did.